# Shell : detect when the user press a key (including arrow keys)

Tags: shell, input, sh

I would like to detect when the user press a key. In order to do that, I used the following command :

```
read -rsn1
```

But it doesn't work for arrow keys.
Thanks.

Comment: Although keyt detection is often possible, it is very problematic, as many scripts use IME (input method editors) where keystrokes and characters do not correlate. Equally, Emoji input often uses pickers which won't work well as decode keystrokes.

Comment: The shell doesn't know anything about the keyboard; it only knows about the bytes that the terminal writes to its standard input. Control by itself doesn't write any bytes, and ArrowUp writes a terminal-specific *sequence* of bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So with the explanations of [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) I've wrote this:

```
function readEscape {

    IFS= read -s -n1 input

    if [ "$input" = $'\E' ]; then

        read -s -n2 input
        echo "control key pressed: $input"

    else

        echo "standard key pressed: $input"

    fi
}

readEscape
```

Comment: `od` isn't strictly needed here, by the way -- you can put nonprintable characters in string literals in bash, so `[[ $input = $'\E' ]]` (`$'\E'` could also be written `$'\x1b'` or `$'\033'`) is a much more efficient (since it requires no subshells, no pipelines, and no commands -- like `od` -- not built into the shell itself) way of checking whether `$input` contains an escape character.

Comment: `[ "$input" = $'\E' ]`, in that case. You can reliably leave out the quotes on the left-hand side of `[[ ]]` (which has its own parsing rules), but not `[ ]` (which is processed the same way as any other command, so unquoted expansions go through string-splitting and globbing). Consider the case where the character being compared is a regular space for a situation where you'll get a concrete error with those quotes missing.

Comment: What does [[ ]] means exactly? What is the deference between it and [ ] ?

Comment: [BashFAQ #31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) goes into the differences in detail. `[` is an alternate name for the POSIX-standardized `test` command; `[[` is a ksh/bash extension inspired by that command but adding lots of extra features (pattern matching, regex support, and a reduced number of failure modes by way of having awareness in the parser).

Comment: Thanks for your explanations.